# Change yeoman's application folder name

Tags: javascript, yeoman

Is there any configuration file or something we can change in yeoman that would set the "app" directory to something else? I work with Zend Framework 2 and it uses the "public" directory as the root yeoman uses "app".

I see that I can directory name in the Grunt.js file but it would be nice to reset the defaults in yeoman.

Comment: Please don't include "Any input is greatly appreciated." in your question. It is useless noise.

Comment: What version of Yeoman are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With version 1.4.7 :

1) For app directory :

Gruntfile.js :

```
var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'www'
};
```

index.html :

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
```

bower.json :

```
"appPath": "app"
```

test/karma.conf.js

```
'app/scripts/**/*.js'
```

2) for the dist directory :

Only in Gruntfile.js

```
var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'www'
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to change the `Gruntfile.js` settings, as from version 1.0 everything is listed here, and build is done by Grunt only.

As they write on the [website](http://yeoman.io/):

> Yo scaffolds out a new application, writing your Grunt configuration
>   and pulling in relevant Grunt tasks that you might need for your
>   build.
>
> Bower is used for dependency management, so that you no longer
>   have to manually download and manage your scripts.
>
> Grunt is used to
>   build, preview and test your project, thanks to help from tasks
>   curated by the Yeoman team and grunt-contrib.

I can't remember where the old settings was in the gruntfile, but in version 1.0 is at line 11 and looks like this:

```
// configurable paths
var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};
```

Comment: Looking at `Gruntfile.js`, I see `app` appear in a few other locations. What was line 11 is now **18**. There's also 61 and 142. Do these lines need to be updated too?

Answer (score 2):

for Angular generator version 0.9.5 works for me:

- change folder name from to app to anything you need, for example 'clientapp'
- edit gruntfile.js, change in appConfig app: 'clientapp'
- edit bower.json change line "appPath": "clientapp"
- in renamed folder find index.html, then find and edit part in comment

  build:js({.tmp,clientapp}) scripts/scripts.js
- in folder test find karma.conf.js and change app to 'clientapp' in files section

Answer (score 1):

Update to 1.0 and edit your Gruntfile.js

```
// configurable paths
var yeomanConfig = {
    **app: 'app',**
    dist: 'dist'
};
```

Comment: I'm on windows and there is no release for windows just yet of the 1.0 beta :(

Comment: Are you interested in the "server" or "dist" build? If you are interested in the dist build you can use the grunt-contibr-copy package to move "app" to "public"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting this, however I have found a few locations which this needs to change and feel that I can add some value:

I use Laravel, which uses an app and public folder, and have never used zend, but am assuming that something similar should apply.

install Yeoman generated app into `yeoman`:

**/[zendapproot]/**

```
mkdir yeoman && cd yeoman
yo angular [appName]
```

**/[zendapproot]/yeoman/**

```
append contents of `/[zendapproot]/yeoman/.gitignore` into `/[zendapproot]/.gitignore`
move everything except the app directory into /[zendapproot]/
```

**edit .bowerrc**

```
{
"directory": "yeoman/app/bower_components"
}
```

**edit Gruntfile.js** to change app and dist folders

```
yeoman: {
  // configurable paths
  app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'yeoman',
  dist: 'public/assets'
},
```

**edit karma.conf.js**

```
files: [
  'yeoman/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'yeoman/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'yeoman/app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'yeoman/app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'yeoman/app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'yeoman/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'yeoman/app/scripts/*.js',
  'yeoman/app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'yeoman/app/test/mock/**/*.js',
  'yeoman/app/test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```

run `grunt test` to ensure that testing is working.

run `grunt serve` to serve the webapp in a testing env

run `grunt` to build which should store the app in `public/assets`

Now this is the part I am not sure on...

At present, I remove `htmlmin` and `rev` from `grunt.registerTask('build'...` in `Gruntfile.js` to stop html minification and to stop assets being renamed.

I then open up my master view template from Laravel (Zend in your case), and change the scripts and styles to that provided in the grunt built index.html `/public/assets/index.html`

If anybody has a better way of tackling the above, please share. e.g. in relation to passing the renamed asset filenames to the zend/laravel application view templates.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project (for angular at least), there is a cmd line arg for this:  --appPath=[newPath]:

```
yo angular --appPath=public
```

**How to change the dist folder name:**

Additionally, for anyone that ends up here looking for how to change the dist folder name (as I did): 
There is no cmd line arg that I could find, so you need to manually edit **Gruntfile.js** at line 21 after creating your project, but before running grunt:

```
// Configurable paths for the application
var appConfig = {
  app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
  //dist: 'dist'
  dist: 'public' 
};
```